# Chartjs - Progressive Line sample from docs is throwing helpers.easing.easeOutQuad is not defined?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Trying to use the sample given here: [Link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/animations/progressive-line-easing.html)
The `easeOutQuad` documentation, in Reactjs

When I try to load the page I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: helpers is not defined

I assume this is because `helpers` has not been imported in the file. I am trying to figure out how to import it, but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here is the code:

```
# I made this import
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

let easing = helpers.easingEffects.easeOutQuad;
# this line is causing the error
# Tried converting this to:
let easing = Chart.helpers.easingEffects.easeOutQuad;
# Errors, because this is not the right import.
```

Then I tried:

```
import helpers from chart.js/helpers;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: chart_js_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.helpers is undefined

Can someone point me to where I can find how to import this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/getting-started/integration.html#helper-functions) here you need to import these funcitons using treeshaking from the helpers package when using ESM:

```js
import { easingEffects} from 'chart.js/helpers';
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how I keep missing things in the docs.